# Find a path in an incidence matrix

Tags: java, matrix, graph, vertex

In an incidence matrix we have:

```
   e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6
v1 1  1  0  0  0  0
v2 0  0  1  1  0  1
v3 0  0  0  0  1  1
v4 1  0  1  0  0  0
v5 0  1  0  1  1  0
```

To find a path, we should find if the last vertex of and edge i is the start of another edge, and the last of the last edge is the first of the first edge.

Can someone help me to find a solution? I understand very well what it is but not how to implement it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incidence matrix in a Graph with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172172/incidence-matrix-in-a-graph-with-java)

Comment: Don't you need a start vertex and a stop vertex? Or are you trying to find a [Hamiltonian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) ?

Comment: @jlordo not duplicate, the other link is for how to create it

Comment: @durron597 I don't search a Hamiltonian path!

Comment: Is the start and end vortex given or do you want to find all the paths ? Finding all paths would be a crazy problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you determine as a path? Do you want to find out if it's possible to visit all node exactly once?

There are two general ways of searching a path: [depth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). If you have a look at some of the examples, it shouldn't be too hard to implement yourself.